# OS X Storyboard Segue dismissController

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, storyboard, segue

I user OS X Storyboard and have created segue for a ViewController with style sheet.

Inside the sheet view is a button to close it. I connected the Button to the dismissController IBAction.

If I run the function dismissController without user interaction the viewController is gone but the sheet will not go away.

Does some one know how to dismiss a ViewController correctly inside a sheet ?

Here a short example what I'am trying. This would be a function from my viewController inside the sheet.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    let chooesSourceDirectoryDialog: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    chooesSourceDirectoryDialog.canChooseDirectories = true
    chooesSourceDirectoryDialog.canChooseFiles = false
    if chooesSourceDirectoryDialog.runModal() == NSOKButton {
        // do some stuff with the selected directory
    } else {
        // here I would close the sheet
        self.dismissController(nil)
    }
}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

A sheet view is a "View", hence you should use

`self.dismissViewController(#The controller name#)`

instead of

`self.dismissController(nil)`

dismissController is used for dismiss multiple controllers.